# Generating Signed APK from Android Source Code without Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, signed-apk

I have bought an android app source code from codecanyon. I want to generate android apk for distribution without android studio. Any alternative?

Reason:
I have some problem installing android studio in my pc which makes it impossible to use android studio.

Comment: Do you have Android SDK in your system?

Comment: without android studio it is quite hard to generate .apk file

Comment: send me source, i can help you to build apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes` in `build.gradle`'s `android` block. For example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
            storeFile file('../key.jks')
            storePassword '...'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            useProguard false
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }   
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

Then from terminal or command prompt in root path of your project, run the following commands:

```
// To generate debug apk
gradlew assembleDebug

// To generate release apk
gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in command line. see the tutorial from official site with this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline)